# Build an extensible system for scraping websites

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions, cloud

Currently, I have a server running. Whenever I receive a request, I want some mechanism to start the scraping process on some other resource(preferably dynamically created) as I don't want to perform scraping on my main instance. Further, I don't want the other instance to keep running and charging me when I am not scraping data.
So, preferably a system that I can request to start scraping the site and close when it finishes.

Currently, I have looked in google cloud functions but they have a cap at 9 min max for every function so it won't fit my requirement as scraping would take much more time than that. I have also looked in AWS SDK it allows us to create VMs on runtime and also close them but I can't figure out how to push my API script onto the newly created AWS instance.

Further, the system should be extensible. Like I have many different scripts that scrape different websites. So, a robust solution would be ideal.
I am open to using any technology. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to push my API script onto the newly created AWS instance.

This is achieved by using [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html):

> When you launch an instance in Amazon EC2, you have the option of passing user data to the instance that can be used to perform common automated configuration tasks and even **run scripts** after the instance starts.

So basically, you would construct your `UserData` to install your scripts, all dependencies and run them. This would be executed when new instances are **launched**.

If you want the system to be scalable, you can lunch your instances in [Auto Scaling Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html) and scale it up or down as you require.

The other option is running your scripts as **Docker containers**. For example using [AWS Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/what-is-fargate.html).

By the way, AWS Lambda has limit of 15 minutes, so not much more than Google functions.

Comment: So, Make a Docker container for each script and upon request push that docker container on AWS Fargate? And does AWS SDK supports making Fargate dynamically via its SDK?

Comment: @GhazanferAnwar There are many ways to achieve that. To build docker images you can use [CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html).